# Read in multiple values in R shiny textInput

Tags: r, shiny, textinput

Is it possible to read in multiple values in textInput in R shiny? Look at a simple example below.  I want to be able to produce a sum (or another R function) on the user entering valueS.  Can a user enter: 1, 2, 3, 4 and the see the sum of these numbers below?

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Copy the line below to make a text input box
  textInput("text", label = h3("Text input"), value = "Enter text..."),

  hr(),
  fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value")))

))




shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # You can access the value of the widget with input$text, e.g.
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$text })

})
```

Comment: Certainly. You just need to split the string and convert the results as number. The tricky part is about formatting, as users do not always enter the data exactly as you would like it.

Comment: The "easiest" solution would be to allow them to enter whatever they want, and then server side `strsplit()` and then add together. But I'd say the best solution would be to have a `selectizeInput`, have all numbers 1 to ....a billion, available, and they could click as many as they want and then you could server side add them together. The `strsplit` option could be weird since they can enter anything they want, with any delimiter they want.

Comment: Change your `output$value` code to the following: `output$value <- renderPrint({ sum(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(input$text, " ")))) })`